# Get location not working on android

Tags: android

With this code I'm trying to get  get the location this code only works the first time I execute the emulator the Ihave to close the emulator in order to work again ,and it doesn't launch any error

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);
        myContext = this;
        position =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.position);
        locationManager=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
                double latitude=location.getLatitude();
                double longitude=location.getLongitude();
                position.setText("lat:"+latitude+" lon:"+longitude);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    101);
        }
        else{
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(location != null){

            }
            else{
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 101: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    } else {
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SecurityException err_permission) {
        }
    }

}
```

and this permision on manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But the position is not shown on the textview, I think I don't missed anything,Do I?Maybe coarse_location permission ?I don'k know what is wrong on this code it has the locationmanager and the listener, and aks form permission...

Comment: Did you debug the code to see what gets called here and what doesn't? Do you get an actual location in onLocationChanged or it never gets called? Try going backwards and see what the last point is where the code still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null){

        }
        else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0,
                    0, locationListener);
        }
```

If you have the location you are not starting periodic updates, you may be looking for this:

```
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0,
                    0, locationListener);
        if(location != null){
              //Do things with the first location
        }
```

So you start with something and keep updating with the listener

Answer (score 0):

If there is a last known location from `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation` then you don't request location updates.